# VLC causes 17.10 to Freeze completely

Tags: gnome, 17.10, vlc, freeze

I'm using `Gnome Wayland` on `Ubuntu 17.10` and whenever I hover over the timeslider of `VLC player` (Full-screen or minimised), the entire screen becomes non reponsive to anything including mouse and keyboard. Only way to get it working is a hard reset or more recently I found out that shutting the lid of my laptop causes it to go to suspend after which I can login again and everything works normally.

Comment: I also have the same issue

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 16.04 I have the same problem. I removed `vlc` and installed  `vlc` from `flatpak` . It works well.

Comment: So is it just a bug of ubuntu's version of vlc? Ive used it for quite a while on 14.04 and then 16.04 but never had any such problem.

Comment: still same problem, also flatpak version dosent work for me